# C# What happens if a web method call has timed out?

Tags: c#

It is basically a conceptual question. I want to confirm if we call a third party web service method and it does not respond in time and c# throws operation timeout exception, does the web method on the other end continue processing the request or it stops further processing as soon as the calling party gets disconnected due to timeout exception?

Comment: The connection will be kept alive until it times out (defined by the server's config) or if a new request is made and the pool is out of connections. https://users.cs.fiu.edu/~downeyt/webdev/timeout

Basically, the server will wait for for reconnection but will only wait so long.

Comment: The server can only recognize a timeout is under three conditions 1) The connection closes and the server handles the close event 2) The client send a message and the server asynchronously process 2nd message while first is still processing 3) 1st message finishes processing and server reads 2nd message